# How to get the SUM of 3 individual columns in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to get the SUM of 3 individual columns. When I try to output I get nothing. What do I do wrong?

Model

```
    $this->db->select('SUM(priceParking) AS price_parking, SUM(priceCharing) AS price_charging, SUM(priceWash) AS price_wash');
    $this->db->from('bestillinger');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

Controller

```
    $data['total_income'] = $this->accounting_model->total_parking_today();
```

View

```
    <span class="info-box-number"> <?php echo $total_income['price_parking']?>  
    <span class="info-box-number"> <?php echo $total_income['price_charging']?>  
    <span class="info-box-number"> <?php echo $total_income['price_wash']?>
```

Comment: did you check in the controller if `print_r($data);` does output anything?, also check if you call the model correctly, most likely you need uppercase `$this->Accounting_model->total_parking_today()` as well as the file Accounting_model.php and the class definition, follow: [Anatomy of a Model](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html?highlight=model#anatomy-of-a-model)

Comment: Please check
var_dump($query->result_array()); die('here);
before returning from model to check if you are getting what you want from db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$this->db->select()` accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names. This is useful if you need a compound select statement where automatic escaping of fields may break them. ([Reference](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id1))

```
$this->db->select('SUM(priceParking) AS price_parking, SUM(priceCharing) AS price_charging, SUM(priceWash) AS price_wash', false);
```